# Link breaks when changing text in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a link button that starts the download of a file. When the button is clicked it will change the text and disable the link. The code works fine in chrome and firefox, but it fails to work in IE.

After playing around I noticed that it was the changing of the text. I tried both vanilla js and jquery.

I do not understand why the code does not work in IE but works on all other browsers.

Here is the JSFIDDLE link: Please make sure you open it in Internet Explorer

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38019/

```js
$('#dl-btn').click(function(){
 $(this).attr('disabled', true);
 $(this).text('Download is starting');

 //return true;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="dl-btn" target="_blank" href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"><strong>Start Download</strong></a>
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Huangism I am using IE 11. I toggled the settings in developer mode and this is true for 9, 10 and edge. (I refuse to test below 9)

Comment: Do you want the text change to be inside of the strong tag or replace the entire content of the anchor?

Comment: Change the text inside of the strong. I just noticed that when I removed the strong tag. The link functioned the way I intended it to.

Comment: Try this `$(this).find('strong').text('Download is starting');`

Comment: @Huangism No luck either. I think i'm just going to have to remove the strong tag.

Comment: What actually happens when you change the text? can you attach a screenshot of the result? You can also try `$(this).text('<strong>Download is starting</strong>');` or reverse the order of things, update text then disable. Or remove one of them and see which statement is causing the actual issue. Better to figure it out then taking a shortcut

Comment: @Huangism The link text changes and the link is disabled but the link isn't executed. .text html escapes so I did .html and still didn't have luck using `$(this).html('<strong>Download is starting</strong>');` Here is a screenshot. [link](https://imgur.com/2SBGk5r)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, so all the js works except the link does not go where it's supposed to go. Did you try removing one of the statements and see if it works. Try commenting out the disabled line first and see if it works. I have a feeling IE is executing the disable too early so the link is disabled then it tries to execute the href

Comment: @Huangism I was able to figure out that it was the .text function. When I removed that it worked. I then removed the `<strong>` tag and added the text function, and it worked. I have concluded that IE does not like having the text changes in a link if there is a nested tag in the link. (`<a href...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `<strong></strong>` tag that was nested in the `<a href></a>` portion. Internet explorer would prevent default behaviour if there was any nested takings in `<a href></a>` e.g `<a href="link"><strong>Test</strong></a>` or `<a href="link"><span>Test</span></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` instead of `.click()`:

```
$('#dl-btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).text('Download is starting');

});
```

Comment: I tried to do this and it didn't work. See this jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38021/

I did find out that the strong tag. Was the issue. I removed <strong> from inside the link and it works...why though.